# T-SQL. Сумма строк столбца, созданного подзапросом.

Tags: sql-server

Доброго времени суток! Начал изучать T-SQL и столкнулся с проблемой, а именно, нельзя применять агрегатные функции к подзапросам. Как можно сделать по другому?

```
Select  
        SUM(@TypeInt -
        ISNULL(
        (
            Select MinusHours
            From Holidays AS H
            Where H.HDate = CalendFilt.Date
        ), 0)) AS [WorksHours]
From    (
        Select      [Date]
        From            Calendar
        Where       [Date] BETWEEN 
                        (Select [HireDate]
                        From        Employees
                        Where   IDEmployee = 1) 
                        AND
                        ISNULL((Select  [DismissalDate]
                        From        Employees
                        Where   IDEmployee = 1), GETDATE())
        ) AS CalendFilt;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Жаль что вы не привели структуры БД и тестовых данных на каком нибудь sqlfiddle.com без них написать совершенно точно рабочий вариант довольно сложно. Могут быть какие то ошибки и неучтенные моменты структуры. Но выходит как то так:

```
select sum(@TypeInt - ISNULL(H.MinusHours,0))
 from Employees E
 join Calendar C
   on C.Date between E.HireDate and ISNULL(E.DismissalDate,GETDATE())
 left join Holidays AS H
   on H.HDate = C.Date
where E.IDEmployee=1
```

Comment: спасибо большое) Здесь важнее было не найти ответ, а найти способ решения. Т.е. отойти от подзапроса и идти в сторону join) Ещё раз, спасибо за ответ)

Comment: @Dronkom Скажем так, подзапросы, особенно в списке выборки - это крайний случай, если без них можно обойтись - стоит обходится без них. Они обычно плохо оптимизируются. Могу сказать, что за мою очень долгую практику у меня ни разу не было желания написать подзапрос внутри агрегатной функции, как то без этого все разруливается :) Если ответ принят, поставьте плиз галочку под рейтингом :)